# How to receive a parameter that arises from the same activity without producing error the first time it runs?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have an activity that is repeated indefinitely and that activity receives a parameter which arises from itself. The problem is that when run gives an error because it is the first time it starts and there is no parameter to receive. The solution that I thought would be an IF-ELSE.
A solution that got me here, is this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (preferences.getInt("first", 0) != 1) {
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putInt("first", 1);
  editor.commit();
   //first time
} else {
      bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
      count=bundle.getInt("countAnterior");
      tv3.setText(""+count);
      //second time
}
```

But the problem is that it works only when the application is installed and what I need is that every time I open the activity work. They proposed me is to reset the value in the OnStop method and OnDestroy, but investigate and I did not know how. I don't know if it works well or propose another solution. Anyway the question is how to receive a parameter that arises from the same activity without producing error the first time it runs?
I appreciate if you provide the code because I am beginner. Sorry if my English is bad, I am Argentine.
Thanks

Comment: Why dont you try with : 
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){code 2nd time}else{code first time}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution gave me JpCrow. It is:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() !=null){
          bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
          count=bundle.getInt("countAnterior");
          tv3.setText(""+count);
         }else{}
```

Thank you very much JpCrow